# SQL Data file size is not reduced after successful completion of RBS data movement?

Tags: rbs

Referring to my previous question - [Installing and Configuring RBS on SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101745/installing-and-configuring-rbs-on-sharepoint-2010)

RBS is installed, configured and successfully moved the data from SQL to BlobStore(~100GB)

```
$cdb = Get-SPContentDatabase "ContentDB_01"
$cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings.MinimumBlobStorageSize=1048576
$cdb.Update()
$rbss = $cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
$rbss.Migrate()
```

However still SQL Data file size is same as before.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you compacted the database?

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you see any free space in the content Database, basically Database not release or shrink himself automatically.

you can run the DB_Spaceused against the content DB to see the free space in the db or you can run the report from SSMS.

If you see the a lot of free space which is equal to the data moved to RBS, then you can shrink the database, or leave as it is(i would recommend) if you have enough space on drives. new content will use that free space.

here are the steps to shrink it.
http://kalaisg.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-shrink-sql-sharepoint-database.html

Comment: Thanks, I could see ~120GB of free space on the SQL, can I shrink the Database? does it affect the performance?

Comment: highly recommended perform the shrinking off peak hours.